# Django: After migration, all model fields with unique=True get IntegrityError Duplicate Entry for Key

Tags: python, django

I have a model with a `uniqueblogname` element that is set to `Unique=True`. In my views, I do something like:

```
try: 
      MyModel.objects.get(uniqueblogname=userinput) #i ask the user to input 
#a name of a blog they want to own on the site (all blogs must have a unique name)
  #if taken then prints some error messages that the blog name is taken.....
except MyModel.DoesNotExist:
      MyModel.objects.create(uniqueblogname=userinput) #if no blog has that name then
   #the blog object is created
```

I recently updated my db by doing dumpdata and loaddata to a brand new blank db and migrating new model changes to this db (I wanted to keep the old db how it was and archive it). Everything went smoothly. New migrations were made without errors. However, now whenever I execute the above check, if I search for any old blogname then I get this error:

```
1062, "Duplicate entry (the user's input here) for key 'uniqueblogname'"
```

However, if I search for a completely new blogname and the object gets created then I search for it again using this check, everything works fine. It seems as if the code for trying to retrieve the old `MyModel` objects does not get properly executed and django tries to create a new `MyModel` only to realize that it would be a duplicate and so throw this error.

The most confusing part about this error is like I said: If I create a completely new blogname and enter it, and the object is created freshly within this new db, this check condition works every time perfectly (so I don't suspect it is a logic issue in my code). However, I can't seem to check my older stuff that I used loaddata to populate.

Any ideas? Very appreciative of any suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: What database backend are you using? Do you have a different collation or storage engine in your new database? Also, might I suggest using [`get_or_create`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create).

Comment: They are both MySQL nothing fancy and nothing different from one another. At least not that I can tell. Does the name of the db itself and the privileged user matter for example? Those are honestly the only different things that I can see.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to comment on your specific case without knowing more. I'd start by looking at the database itself and seeing if there's anything different about your old rows as opposed to the newly created rows.

I do want to point out that your current code has a race condition, since another process could insert a row with the same name in between the `get()` and the `create()`. I suggest using [`get_or_create()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create) instead.

> This method is atomic assuming correct usage, correct database configuration, and correct behavior of the underlying database.

Comment: Thanks to both you and knbk for pointing this out. I will change the statements to get_or_create() but the problem still remains.

Comment: I looked at the db. They look the same to me except the settings such as the MySQL db name and the privileged user etc. Here is my workflow:
1.) For my previous db I did: python manage.py dumpdata > dump.json
2.) Then I created a new db, changed my settings.py to this new one, did syncdb then loaddata into it. 
3.) Then I simply switched out the models.py file to the new one and migrated to sync the changes. Everything went fine with no errors. Can this all work with the database structure being different?

Comment: @SwAvGuy: Hmm, it almost seems as though the index governing the unique constraint isn't being populated properly on `loaddata`. See what SQL your `get()` is generating and then try it yourself directly on the database. Use database tools to see if the index is being hit, and see why the query works as expected with newly created rows but not the one you imported. I don't see anything wrong with what you're doing from a Django perspective, so I think you're going to have to dig into the db.